# Project upgrade/move from Yii to Laravel

Tags: laravel, yii

Is it even possible to do something like that? To move quite heavy project from Yii 1 to Laravel 5?
Maybe I'm a bit unrealistic, but question is question. :)

Comment: Why is it not possible? People change languages over the years, so changing frameworks is no big deal!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about the difference between Yii and Laravel is that Yii is more well-suited to data-heavy applications whereas Laravel is great if your application needs to be flexible and be able to act as an API.

Comment: May I ask why you want to switch to Laravel?

Comment: It would be easier to move to Yii 2 ;)